# how to excute "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools/stable/dist/js/axs_testing.js" url in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write the below code using python selenium but could not able to do that as I am new to python and selenium. Can someone please help?

```
val driver = org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver //use driver of your choice
val jse = driver.asInstanceOf[JavascriptExecutor]
jse.executeScript(scala.io.Source.fromURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleChrome/" +
   "accessibility-developer-tools/stable/dist/js/axs_testing.js").mkString)
val report = jse.executeScript("var results = axs.Audit.run();return axs.Audit.createReport(results);")
println(report)
```